# Windows cmd.exe - How to keep folder name intact in command?

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

As per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/768218/452924), I'm trying to run an `ffmpeg` script through a folder recursively.

I run:

```
for /r "W:\Exports\1 - Dailies\" %f in (*.mov) do ffmpeg -i %f -vf fps=6/60 still%05d.jpg
```

But `cmd.exe` is only seeing the name of the folder as `1` instead of `1 - Dailies`:

```
W:\Exports\1: No such file or directory
```

How can I modify this command to execute the `ffmpeg` command for the contents of the `1 - Dailies` folder?

Comment: Filenames with spaces always need to be quoted - try  `...ffmpeg -i "%f" ...`. If that doesn't work, you'll need to use the 8.3 version of the file; that's an escape I don't recall.

Comment: Use `cd /d "W:\Exports\1 - Dailies"` first then use `for /r` without that folder path.